# Selenium webdriver code how to iterate through hidden row in a table/grid

Tags: html-table, hidden

I need code how to iterate/get values from hidden rows of a table.I can only get actual row counts only for the on screen rows,but if scrolling down manually from the last row and another hidden row will be visible on screen,the first previous row will be hidden.

The grid has only 20 rows attribute, the on screen and hidden rows are dynamically looping within the same 20 attributes by scrolling down.

The sample below code can only iterate only on the on screen rows not the hidden rows. Please, i need a code to be able to get all the values and number of rows of the values.I am new in Selenium

```
    List<WebElement> col=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='rows']/tr"));
   List<WebElement> rows =driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='rows']/tr[1]/td")); 

        for (int i =1;i<rows.size();i++) { 
         for (int j =1;j<col.size();j++){
             Webelement vText=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='rows']/tr["+i+"]/td["+j+"]"));
             vText.getText();
             system.out.println("Print out the values" + vText);
         }


        }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show some effort with self written unworking code

Comment: Could please provide a working code for the issue raised